# AWS API Gateway Get Method How to Pass API Key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-api-gateway

I have a working AWS API Gateway GET method. I want to secure it using an API key, so I've created an API key and usage plan, etc.

So previously when I wanted to call the GET method, I would just type a URL with the appropriate parameters into the browser and send it. However, now that we've introduced the API key into the mix, I'm not sure how to call it.

I'm aware of the command line GET and curl tools. Which of these 3 tools (browser, GET, CURL) can accomplish this task and what syntax do I need to use to make the request to the GET method passing the API key?

Comment: You have to pass the key in the `x-api-key` HTTP header. You need to search how to set custom HTTP headers in whatever tool you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

Mark B is right, I'm just copying because it's the right answer.

You must pass an HTTP header named `x-api-key` with the API Key as the value. One tool is cURL, another is Postman.